# What is actually copied to the clipboard when I copy an image?

Tags: images, clipboard

Please forgive me if this is answered somewhere.

When I right click and copy an image from the browser, what actually gets stored in the clipboard?

Is that an image? or some base64 URL? or an actual URL of the image?

Is it same for locally stored images as well?

Comment: A copy of the image is stored.

Comment: it will be the binary data of the image if you selected "Copy Image". if you select Copy Image Address or Copy Link Address or somthing else, it will be the url, generally in UTF-8. One thing you must understand is that any image you see on a page has already been downloaded to your system. your browser downloads all the pieces-parts of the page and then renders them for you to view, so the file is already present in cache/tmp.

Comment: What OS? I believe in Linux (X) [the browser claims it has a selection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316890/108618) and any client that wants to paste contacts it to receive the image. So storing anything is up to the browser. As long as it can serve the image when asked, it will work, even if the image gets downloaded anew. A special client can retrieve every new selection and assert ownership of the clipboard, so the selection can be retrieved after the original owner terminates. The special client can store the actual data in any way (verbatim, compressed, encrypted, in a cloud, …).

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am a web developer and was thinking of capturing a part of the page on button click in chrome extension and then copying the screenshot to the clipboard. Is this thing even possible?

Comment: see if this works for you: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ Note that of course this would need to execute as client side script, so any actions outside of the page itself may or may not be allowed by the sandbox in the browser. good luck.